# Creating vector using Sentence

Tags: python, machine-learning, project, sentiment-analysis

I want to do sentiment analysis and created SVM Model in python, which uses points(coordinates) to plot a vector, but only works with numeric values.
I want to map a sentence to a vector.
Example: "The food is very delicious" converted to (a,b) co-ordinate which signifies whether a sentence is +ve or -ve.
Is there a way to convert the sentence to a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NLTK

```py
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

data = "All work and no play makes jack a dull boy, all work and no play"
print(word_tokenize(data))
```

This will output:

```sh
['All', 'work', 'and', 'no', 'play', 'makes', 'jack', 'dull', 'boy', ',', 'all', 'work', 'and', 'no', 'play']
```

More information can be found here: 
https://pythonspot.com/tokenizing-words-and-sentences-with-nltk/

You then need to turn these words into numbers the easiest way to do that is to simply use their indexes.

```py
tokens = (word_tokenize(data))
indexes = [idx for idx in range(len(tokens))]
```

No we need to normalise so that the numbers range between 0 and 1.

```py
indexes = indexes / Len(indexes)
```

Now we can use tensorflow to convert these indexes into a vector.

```py
vector = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    indexes, dtype=tf.float)
)
```

Please note after using your tensor you'll need to denormalize your data like so:

```py
Indexes = indexes * Len(indexes)
```

To turn this back into a word:

```py
tokens[x]
```

Where X is the index of the word you want to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this information, I just want to get an Idea, how i can convert the tokens into a single vector.

Comment: Added more detail to my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: @AtharvUpadhyay if this answered your question could you consider marking it as the accepted answer?